# JQuery.Chosen: Is there a "blur" event?

Tags: blur, jquery-chosen

According the [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html), there is no "blur" (losing focus) event for a select list modified by Chosen. I have tried jquery's `$("#myselect").blur()` but that does not seem to fire either when the Chosen-modified select list loses focus.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/q3g3pnb2/

Note the blur event is not triggered when the first select list loses focus. Is there another way to capture the blur event when using Chosen?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying run some event when the select value change, you can do:

```
$('.my_select_box').on('change', function(evt, params) {
   do_something(evt, params);
 });
```

As you can see here [in the documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events)

Answer (score 0):

I need this also.  There is no blur event for jquery chosen.  I found this 'hack' to the jquery chosen js file but I can't get it to work.
Here is the code...maybe you will have better luck:

```
    Chosen.prototype.close_field = function () {
    $(document).unbind("click.chosen", this.click_test_action);
    this.active_field = false;
    this.results_hide();
    this.container.removeClass("chosen-container-active");
    this.form_field_jq.trigger('chosen:blur', { chosen: this }); /* SmokinMedia */
    this.clear_backstroke();
    this.show_search_field_default();
    return this.search_field_scale();
};

Chosen.prototype.activate_field = function () {
    this.container.addClass("chosen-container-active");
    this.active_field = true;
    this.search_field.val(this.search_field.val());
    this.form_field_jq.trigger('chosen:focus', { chosen: this }); /* SmokinMedia */
    return this.search_field.focus();
};
```