# Function on Focus Out for Chosen Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-chosen

I use the chosen library  throughout my application for select boxes.

https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

I would like to use something along the lines of

```
$("form :input, form select").blur(function() { });
```

to fire a function on focus out for my inputs and selects. This works fine for my inputs, but for my select options the function will not attach, due in part I think to Chosen overriding the

```
<select>
```

html element.

Any one have any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328228/jquery-chosen-is-there-a-blur-event).

Comment: Thank you, didn't see this.